# Does it really make sense to talk about the color of gluons?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, gauge-invariance, strong-force

It is my understanding that by enforcing SU(3) gauge invariance on our lagrangian of 3-colored quark fields, we are forced to accept the existence of 8 new massless vector fields, the gluons. The 8 here comes directly from the dimension of SU(3).

That being said I often see discussions about the gluons in terms of linear combinations of $r\bar r$, $b\bar b$,   etc.

This simply cant be the nature of the gluons though can it? Because it seems to imply that the number of colors and the number of gluon fuelds are not independant, while they clearly are.

Certainly gluons are not singlets in color space and so they must have color, but it doesnt make sense to me that this color of the gluons would be some mapping directly from quark color.

Thanks to anyone with the insight and time to share it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quarks transform according to the fundamental representation $\mathbf{3}$ of SU(3), and the antiquarks according to the conjugate representation $\mathbf{\overline 3}$. The gluons transform according to the adjoint representation $\mathbf{8}$.

The adjoint representation is contained in the product of the fundamental representation and its conjugate:

$$\mathbf{3}\otimes \mathbf{\overline 3} = \mathbf{8}\oplus \mathbf{1}$$

Therefore gluons are conventionally labeled using color-anticolor combinations, avoiding the color singlet combination $(r\overline{r}+b\overline{b}+g\overline{g})/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Awesome do you have a any sources/papers/books I could find more about this?

Comment: As well; in a universe where we had say, 4 or 5 colors and 8 gluons, how would this work?

Comment: @Craig, are you familiar with representation theory? A big concept is that the same group can be "represented" with larger or smaller vector spaces. In this case, the quarks have the _minimum_ number of vectors needed to realize SU(3) symmetry, and the gluons have (very loosely) that _maximum_ number of vectors that can have the SU(3) symmetry, one for each dimension.

If we had 4 colors, then we would instead want $4\otimes \bar 4 = 15\oplus 1$, and we would have 15 gluon fields for the 4 colors.

Comment: The adjoint reprsentation of SU(n) has dimension $n^2-1$. So if you have 4 colors there need to be 15 gluons and if you have 5 colors there need to be 24 gluons.

Comment: I’ll let others suggest the best references. But you need to clarify what you main interest is. The mathematics of representation theory? (For example, how do you figure out how an arbitrary product of irreducible representations decomposes into irreducible representations?) The physics of QCD, or the whole Standard Model? The reason why quantum field theory involves group representations? Etc.

Comment: @G.Smith, I was under the impression that the SU(3) incariance had nothing to do with the fact that there are 3 colors, at least that's what I was taught

Comment: SU(3) is the symmetry group of QCD in the same way that U(1) is the symmetry group of QED. As a result, QCD has 3 kinds of “charge”, called colors, just as QED has one kind of charge (the electric kind). For confirmation, see Wikipedia’s  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics. Is it possible your teacher was talking about the three generations of matter rather than the three colors?

Comment: My teacher was certainly discussing color. It was Introduced ground up, starting with the assertion that there are 3 different fermion fields, which are initially only distinguishable by a property called color. We put these three fields into a tuple, call that tuple field a quark, & demand that our lagrangian is invariant under SU(3) operations on that tuple. Thus the 3 colors force a representation of the elements of SU(3) but in theory there is absolutely nothing wrong with starting with 4 color fields, and still having that same gauge invariance. Wed simply be forced to work in the 4repres

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85596/discussion-between-craig-and-g-smith).

Comment: @G.Smith. Shouldn't it be $(r\overline{r}+b\overline{b}+g\overline{g})/\sqrt{3},$ i.e. division by $\sqrt{3}$ instead of multiplication?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, and thank you for catching my mistake. I’ve just edited my answer to fix it,

Answer (score 3):

The gluons are generators of the SU(3) gauge group; whatever notation is used to describe the fundamental representation can be extended to higher representations through their embedding in tensor products of the fundamental (and its dual.) [Also, by "sums" of $r\bar r$, $b\bar b$, etc., do you really mean products?]

Comment: Oops I mean linear combinations of products of $r\bar r$, $b\bar b$, etc